# Increase size of div while adding to li

Tags: javascript, css

GOAL:

I am working on a personal project to develop a navigation with menus and submenus. In the parent list there is an input and when I submit to the input I want it to add to the menu. When it adds I want the size of the container it is in to increase with it.

PROBLEM:

When I add to the list I cannot get the correct formula to increase the size of the box as I add to the list. I get items listed but they eventually fall off the boundaries of the box. See below for what it looks like:

[image: first]

Here is how it looks before I add anything:

[image: second]

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drop Down Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>

<!--Navbar-->
  <header class="container">
    <nav id="nav1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">Downloads <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="dropdown1">
       <ul id="listAdd">
        <li>Sample Menu</li>
        <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
        <li class="submenu1"><a href="#">Television <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E-Books</a></li>
        <li class="submenu2"><a href="#" >Software <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>

      </ul>
      <input placeholder="Input" class="inputBar" id="form"><a href="#" id="searchGlass"><i class="fas fa-search fa-xs" id="magGlass"></i></a>
    </div>
        <div class="dropdown2">
       <ul>
        <li>Top Movies</li>
        <li><a href="#">Friday</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Avengers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dark Knight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transformers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Notebook</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="dropdown3">
       <ul>
        <li>Top Software</li>
        <li><a href="#">Adobe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gimp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rosetta Stone</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
<!--End of Navbar-->


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my javascript for this portion:

```
 const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown1');
 const list = document.querySelector('#listAdd');


document.getElementById("searchGlass").addEventListener("click", function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); 
    fn = document.getElementById("form").value;
    console.log(fn);
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fn));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    let increase = 10;
    dropdown.style.width = '300px' + increase;
});
```

Adding CSS:

```
.container{
  width:1920px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.dropdown1{
  background-color:#444444;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  margin-left:204px;
  margin-top:0px;
  display:none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #999;
  /*if I do not use position absolute everything will get pushed down*/
  position: absolute;



}

.dropdown1:before, .dropdown1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown1:before {
  left: 19px;
  border: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #444444;
}
.dropdown1:after {
  left: 20px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #444444;
}

.dropdown1 ul{
  padding:20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown1 li{
  padding-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.dropdown1 li:first-child{
  color:white;
}

.dropdown1 a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-size:12px;

}
.dropdown1 li a:active {
   background-color: black;
}
.dropdown1 li:hover {
   background-color: black;
}


.dropdown1 input{
  color:white;
  border:none;
  padding-top:5px;
  height:10px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.dropdown1 li:nth-child(3) i{
  color:white;
  margin-left:90px;
}
.dropdown1 li:nth-child(5) i{
  color:white;
  margin-left:98px;
}

#listAdd{
  margin:0;
}


.inputBar{
  width:120px;
  background-color:#444444;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #999;
}

input, select, textarea{
    color: white;
}

#searchGlass{
  margin-left:10px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;

}

#magGlass{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Include relevant CSS as well. A new li should not overlap its container unless some CSS is restricting the height of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dropdown1{
    height: 300px; // <-- don't use height
    min-height: 300px; // <-- use min height
}
```

Make sure that you use min-height instead of a fixed height if you want your div to expand as new items are added to it.

Comment: thank you so much I tried so many different ways and I completely forgot about that.